# Log Collector returns partial data

Tags: android, email, logging, logcat

I am trying to get the logs from the android phone while not connected to the PC. I have downloaded the Log Collector but for some reason I get only partial data and cannot see the whole data I can see via logcat. Is there a way to get the complete data or just use the logcat -filters to get the logs and send them over e-mail?
By partial data I mean that I see only system info but not the info sent from my apps to the logger (even after a few secs - so I don't think it is lost after 64K buffer is full)

Thanks
  Simon

Comment: Please define "partial data". LogCat is a 64KB ring buffer, so you will not get anything older than the last 64KB or so of material.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on devices running ICS and later.  Previously it would stream everything, but now I've noticed it's only showing log lines beginning with "D" not "W" like previously.